# How do I add a new complex entry to a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures, express

I have a JavaScript data structure like the following in my Node.js/Express web app:

```
var users = [
    { username: 'x', password: 'secret', email: 'x@x.com' }
  , { username: 'y', password: 'secret2', email: 'y@x.com' }
];
```

After receiving posted form values for a new user:

```
{ 
  req.body.username='z', 
  req.body.password='secret3', 
  req.body.email='z@x.com'
}
```

I'd like to add the new user to the data structure which should result in the following structure:

```
users = [
    { username: 'x', password: 'secret', email: 'x@x.com' }
  , { username: 'y', password: 'secret2', email: 'y@x.com' }
  , { username: 'z', password: 'secret3', email: 'z@x.com' }
];
```

How do I add a new record to my users array using the posted values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [push method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add elements to the end of an array.

```
var users = [
    { username: 'x', password: 'secret', email: 'x@x.com' }
  , { username: 'y', password: 'secret2', email: 'y@x.com' }
];

users.push( { username: 'z', password: 'secret3', email: 'z@x.com' } )
```

You could also just set `users[users.length] = the_new_element` but I don't think that looks as good.

Comment: How can I substitute the post values for the hard-coded values?  For example:

`user.push ({ username: 'req.body.username', password: 'req.body.password', email: 'req.body.email' } )`

Comment: Just do req.body.username, without the quotes. The quotes are turning things into strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can add items to an array in many ways:

[Push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) - adds to the end (think stack)

[Unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) - adds to the beginning (think queue)

[Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) - generic (push and unshift are wrappers around this)