# Saving node.js post data to show all records that have been added since the web application was started

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a web application using node.js that has a form containing basic information about a person.  I need to have all records that have been added since the web application was started display on the submit page.

I believe that I need to create an array to store this information but this is where my confusion starts.  I'm not sure where to create the array to add information to.  I suspect it should be in app.js where I call app.post('/add', routes.add);

I think it should maybe something like this going from an example I found here [How do I add a new complex entry to a javascript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161895/how-do-i-add-a-new-complex-entry-to-a-javascript-array):

```
// Routes

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.post('/add', routes.add);

var people = [{name, country, date, email, phone}];
people.push({name, country, date, email phone});
```

However the array looks like it will only hold enough information for 1 person.

Please let me know if my question is not clear enough and I will try to clarify

Thanks in advance!

Edit:  I believe that when I am calling routes.add this code is executed from my index.js file

```
exports.add = function(req, res){
    res.render('add', { title: 'Person added',
            name: req.body.name,
            country: req.body.country,
            date: req.body.birthday,
            email: req.body.email,
            phone: req.body.phone});
};
```

and in my add.jade file:
    h1 Info Added
    p Name: #{name}
    p Country: #{country}
    p Date: #{date}
    p Email: #{email}
    p Phone: #{phone}

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect first of all... Object should have key value pair.

Comment: What do you do with a record when it is "added" (i.e. what happens in `routes.add`). Do you save it to a database, save it in a session, or something else?

Comment: @Sarah what you're doing in add is simply rendering the add template with the 'person' data passed to it. You need to 'store' the person somewhere. Looks like your intent is to store it in memory in the people array. If so move the people array declaration to the index.js file and in your add handler push the person data onto the people array.

Comment: @MoizRaja  Thank you.  It took me almost 30 minutes trying to figure out how to even word my question.  It's a painfully slow process for me to learn this help but I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to maybe get you started.

### Database

I suggest you move the database to another file, that way you may replace it with a 'real' database later. Ie. do something like this:

- create a lib directory in app root,
- create a db.js in that directory,
- put this code in the db.js:

  > ```
  >  var database = [],
  >     counter = 0;
  >     // add method adds a new object to db.
  >     exports.add = function(person) {
  >       person.id = counter;
  >       counter = counter + 1;
  >       database.push(person);
  >       return id; // we return id, so that we can use it as a reference to this object.
  >     }
  >     // get method retreives the object by id.
  >     exports.get = function(id) {
  >       return database[id]; // this will return undefined if there is no such id
  >     };
  >     exports.list = function(){
  >       return database;
  >     }
  > ```

Now you have a database.

### Controllers

You use the db in other files like this:

```
 var people = require('lib/db');
// or if you're in a routes directory,require('../lib/db') or appropriate path
 people.add({name: 'Sarah'}); // returns 0
 people.add({name: 'Zlatko'}); // returns 1
 people.get(1); // returns {name: 'Zlatko'}
```

Now in your routes/index.js you can include your database and have this to save or retreive an user or all users. Somehing similar to your exports.add:

```
var id = people.add({name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email});
res.render('add', people.get(id));
```

You can also create a 'people' view and just pass it `{people: people.list()}` object as parameters array.

I didn't include any validation, checking, anything ,to make the example more clear. This db can hold more then one person, and it's enough to get you started. And I think it is clear in what it does.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't add the View, as you seem to know your way around Jade.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  It's from an earlier project but it really does help clarify things for me